# Splitting a fraction into two

Tags: fractions, newton-raphson

I have the following question: How do they go from step (2) to step (3)?
They split a fraction and somehow make $ x^3_n $ into $ \frac{x_n}{3}$  as well and I don't follow ... It's a take on Newtons Method.

[image: This is the equation ...]

Comment: Distribute the negative, break the numerator into parts and simplify the second term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it just the fact that $$-\left( \dfrac {a-b}c \right )=-\left(\dfrac ac -\dfrac bc\right) =-\dfrac ac +\dfrac bc$$

Comment: But where did the power of 3 from $x$ go? Is $x/3$ somehow the same as $x^3/3x^2$ ? ... Yes it is. Thanks ... But how come the negative w turns into a positive one?

Comment: @mathnewbie there are two minus signs in (2) and they cancel out.

Comment: Ah, yeah. I see, thanks.

Comment: Yes, you figured out the power thing. The signs all change because the whole thing is being subtracted. Will add that to answer.